# Ubuntu One Music store plugin not working in Rhythmbox

Tags: 11.10, rhythmbox, ubuntu-one

Why did Canonical not update the Ubuntu One Music plugin for Rhythmbox in 11.10? When in 11.10 it's not even an option to install it like in 11.04.

Comment: I think it's because the Music Store exists in Banshee now and it is the default music app for Ubuntu now.

Comment: Yeah, but it says they still support Rhythmbox in the Software Center. You would think they would like to make more money by still keeping that plugin on a popular software that many probably still use instead of Banshee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox-ubuntuone-music-store/+changelog:
Deleted in oneiric-release (Reason: not ported to GTK 3, FTBFS)